# How to save responses to database in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have a simple post method that accepts temperature and checks is the temperature is greater than or equals to 37.4 and returns a response as cleared or not cleared.

```
 @PostMapping(value = "/temperature")
    public ResponseEntity<?> Temperature(@Valid @RequestBody Activation activation) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
            Temperature temperature = new Temperature();
            temperature.setStatus(activation.getStatus());
            temperature.setTemperature(activation.getTemp());
                if (db_activation.getCode().equals(code)) {
                    temperature.setSource("VENUE");
                    temperatureRepository.save(temperature);
                    return ResponseEntity.ok(activation.getTemp() < 37.4 ? "Cleared" : "Not cleared"); 
                }
            }
```

how can I insert the response to Status column (which can be cleared or not cleared) to the database and will it be a post request or a put? Please suggest how to do that

Comment: 1. Do you want to insert the response "Cleared" or "Not Cleared" in status attribute of temperature object?
2. If you are changing the entire temperature object, you should use POST, else try to use PUT if the changes to attributes are minimal.

Comment: Hi @DP3 i want to insert the response cleared or not cleared  in status attribute of temperature object

Comment: You should check the logic over there something like

 temperature.setStatus(activation.getTemp() < 37.4 ? "Cleared" : "Not cleared");

This will set the correct status and later in the response entity, just return whatever value was stored in status field

Comment: thank you very much @DP3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the status, you can use something like below,

```
 temperature.setStatus(activation.getTemp() < 37.4 ? "Cleared" : "Not cleared")
```

If you want to create the resource, POST should be the method, for updates, PUT should be used.

Answer (score 0):

Choosing the right request type is just a matter of convention. Technically you could perform any operation with any type of request. By convention: POST sends some fresh data tonthe server, PUT sends an update of the server's data. So if it's a persisted data, POST would be "add" and PUT would be "update".

You could do it in the same method, like so:

```
if (activation.getTemp()< 37.4) {
    temperature.setStatus("Cleared");
} else {
    temperature.setStatus("Not cleared");
}
```

instead of this line:

```
temperature.setStatus(activation.getStatus());
```